# How to properly use Unit Tests (in any language)

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I've never really written unit tests before (or tests, for that matter, really). I tend to obsessively run/compile after writing even the smallest bit of code to check for errors. I've been doing a bit of reading up on unit tests lately, and I'm curious how to best go about using/implementing them. My main language as of late has been Python, but I think this is a pretty language agnostic question. Does anyone have some tips (or good reading) on how to do this properly?

Thanks!

Comment: "I'm curious how to best go about using/implementing them"?  You don't know how the `unittest` package works?  You don't know how to do Test Driven Development?  What help do you want?  It helps to be very **specific** on what you can do and what you're failing to do.  What have you tried?  What are you unable to do?

Comment: IF it's language agnostic, why is it tagged with Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest [Chapter 13](http://diveintopython.net/unit_testing/index.html) of [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/index.html).

Comment: Awesome. I don't know why I didn't think to look there; I typically look in there for things I'm unsure of, if I can't find it (or understand it easily) in the Python documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unit testing is one thing, another thing to consider is test driven development, where the act of writing the tests first affects the design/ feel of the finally delivered code - hopefully for the better. I find this helps especially if the problem domain is not fully understood at the start of programming.

Clarke Ching does a good one hour talk about TDD using excel. If you spend an hour reading through this, you should get the idea.

http://www.clarkeching.com/files/tdd_for_managers_and_nonprogrammers_using_excell_and_vba_final.pdf

You know you have arrived with unit testing when xUnit Test Patterns is an enjoyable read. http://www.amazon.co.uk/xUnit-Test-Patterns-Refactoring-Signature/dp/0131495054/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1288638075&sr=8-1

That is probably a big ask initially though, and I would suggest something thinner about either refactoring or TDD would be a more gentle introduction to this fascinating subject.

Answer (score 1):

I like this one: [The Art of Unit Testing](http://www.manning.com/osherove/). The examples are in .Net, but that should not be a problem. I don't know any book with examples in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using a framework such as [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.2/) which is built on unittest and follows the same principles but takes much of the scaffolding out of the way for you.

Answer (score 0):

An open source utility library that I use when writing Unit Tests is [ApprovalTests](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/) - there is also a [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0C32F89E8BBB5368&feature=view_all) video series on how to use this library with .Net languages (the ideas can be applied to other languages and the ApprovalTests library is available for other [langauges](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/?q=node/6) (Java, PHP, more) as well.